# Date format ends before converting entire input string

Tags: ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, oracle, validation

**This is My Error I'm using best in place and I want it to update my sample_qty column this table does not have an id column so I did a work around for it but even after doing that I keep getting this error.**

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (OCIError: ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string: SELECT "SAMPLE_QTY".* FROM "SAMPLE_QTY"  WHERE "SAMPLE_QTY"."EMPLOYEE_ID" = 'JQIS' AND "SAMPLE_QTY"."TRANSACTION_DATE" = TO_DATE('2014-11-13 00:00:00 UTC','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') ORDER BY CREATE_DATE DESC):
  app/controllers/samples_controller.rb:31:in `update'

***Rails 3.1.8
Oracle DB***

**This is my model**

```
default_scope order("CREATE_DATE DESC")
set_table_name :sample_qty
set_primary_keys :employee_id, :create_date
attr_accessible :sample_qty, :create_date
belongs_to :labor
paginates_per 20
validates :transaction_date,
        date: { after: Proc.new { Time.now },
                before: Proc.new { Time.now + 1.day } }

def transaction_date=(new_date)
  self[:transaction_date] = Date.strptime(new_date.to_s, "%m/%d/%Y")
end

def date=(new_date)
  if new_date.blank?
    self[:date] = nil
  else
    self[:date] = Date.strptime(new_date.to_s, "%m/%d/%Y")
  end
end

def create_date=(new_date)
  self[:create_date] = Date.strptime(new_date.to_s, "%m/%d/%Y")
end
end
```

**This is my controller**

```
def sample_qty
  @samples = Samples.find(params[:employee_id, :sample_qty])
end

 def edit
   @samples = Samples.find(params[:employee_id])
 end

 def update
   @employee_id = params[:id]
   @samples.assign_attributes({:create_date => Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")})
   @samples.update_attributes(params[:samples])
   @samples.validates_datetime :create_date
     respond_with_bip(@samples)
 end
 end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the quoted error message, you have
`"SAMPLE_QTY"."TRANSACTION_DATE" = TO_DATE('2014-11-13 00:00:00 UTC','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')`
If you could get rid of the `UTC` bit (including the blank in front of it), which is exactly, what the picture has no equivalent for, it should work just fine.
See [Oracle TO_DATE docu](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions203.htm#SQLRF06132).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are doing:

```
@samples.assign_attributes({:create_date => Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")})
```

But then you are parsing a different date format:

```
Date.strptime(new_date.to_s, "%m/%d/%Y")
```

In one it is being delimited with forward slashes instead of dashes.